# Yammer iframe authentication is redirecting to https://www.yammer.com/session/new instead of logging me in

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, yammer

The client side flow [described here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2) was working in an iframe until about a month ago. We are working from an Modern SharePoint environment (SPFx webpart) and Yammer Office 365 Identity Enforcement is Enabled so when I am logged in to SharePoint/Office 365 the iframe should automatically authenticate and return to the configured redirect page with my token. Currently it is moving me to *https://www.yammer.com/session/new* where I will need to login, which off course will not work in an hidden iframe. I see the same behavior in an popup in Chrome (also taken to the session/new page). The popup login in IE is working though (while the Iframe isn't).

Lot's of our customers find this popup disturbing and on most browsers popups also aren't enabled automatically. Therefore lot's of users aren't authenticated to the Yammer API and some of our functions (like showing comments, commentscount etc) aren't working as expected. The iframe login was providing us with the possibility to login silently.

Can someone help us out or point us in the right direction? Many thanks in advance!

*More information and a uservoice:*

- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/790
  h
- https://yammer.uservoice.com/forums/399627-yammer/suggestions/36909883-add-support-for-an-iframe-login-to-authenticate-to

Comment: Have you opened a support case for this? This is the best channel given that you experienced an unexpected change in your solution. Specifically, I'd be looking at a trace of all the HTTP requests (Fiddler is ideal) and looking for X-Frame-Options headers. I'd also want to understand more on the complete authentication scenario (e.g. is the behaviour the same on and off the company network? Integrated Windows Auth vs Forms-based auth). A trace will show the truth on the auth setup too.

Comment: HI Bryan, Thanks for your reply. I have opened a support case and recreated the failing scenario on a tenant they gave me. Sadly as soon they went to the development team with this example the development team rejected it because the iframe login isn't a scenario which is in their documentation and therefore not supported.
The problem is happening on a new session in Chrome. The iframe is going to https://www.yammer.com/<yammer network id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<our client id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<redirect uri on the same tenant>.

Comment: When coming there it is redirected to www.yammer.com//session/new with the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN. The problem is that we have to log in by hand on this page. (this is also happening in the popup) In IE the same is happening in the iFrame, but the popup is login in just fine. On the popop I can see a retrun header with Set-Cookie: logged_in_from_office365=true; path=/; secure, on the iframe I'm getting Set-Cookie: return_to=<request uri>

Comment: The behavior is the same on and off the company network and happens on some spfx webparts and classic pages created in SharePoint. We are logged in to SharePoint using Integrated Windows Auth (SSO). We've got our product running for like 100 customers and they all have the same problem on a new session

Comment: hi @pkmelee337, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Well, I resolved it with a workaround by retrieving the comments in an web application and fixing the authentication server side. However this scenario won't work if the user needs to be authenticated with his own credentials. It seems someone om the Spfx team did something with the issue here though as he merged something. Didn;t have the time yet to check it out though. (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/790)